# How to calculate the mode of a set of rows by group in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'var_name': ['r1','r2','r3','var', 'r1','r2','r3','var'],
                    'group': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                    'value': [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]})
```

I want a new column in this dataframe, which will contain 1 if the `value` is larger than the median of `value` column of the rows where `var_name` is in `['r1','r2','r3']` by `group`, otherwise 0

The output dataframe should look like:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'var_name': ['r1','r2','r3','var', 'r1','r2','r3','var'],
                        'group': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                        'value': [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9],
                        'test': [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]})
```

Explanation of output dataframe:
The median of `r1,r2,r3` for `group a` is `2`, so rows `r3` & `var` get a 1 in the `test` column

is there a pythonic way of doing that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is filter only rows matched by `r` values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), aggregate `median` and last [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by groups with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and last convert to `0,1` values by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
s = foo[foo['var_name'].isin(['r1','r2','r3'])].groupby('group')['value'].median()

foo['test'] = foo['group'].map(s).lt(foo['value']).view('i1')
```

Or another idea with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace no nmatched values to `NaN`s and then is created new `Series` for compare by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `median`:

```
foo['test'] = (foo['value'].where(foo['var_name'].isin(['r1','r2','r3']))
                           .groupby(foo['group'])
                           .transform('median')
                           .lt(foo['value'])
                           .view('i1'))

print (foo)

  var_name group  value  test
0       r1     a      1     0
1       r2     a      2     0
2       r3     a      3     1
3      var     a      4     1
4       r1     b      6     0
5       r2     b      7     0
6       r3     b      8     1
7      var     b      9     1
```